# Where to store "global objects" in a Redux app. Think FB / AWS SDK object

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am using Redux and I am adding the AWS SDK, but you can think of Facebook SDK too. To use it I need to initialize it

```
// Import the AWS SDK
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Set credentials and region
// This can also be done directly on the service client
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-west-1', credentials: {YOUR_CREDENTIALS}});

var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
```

Do I need to configure it everywhere I need to use it? Whats the best practice?

Comment: Bear in mind that in Node (and by extension Webpack, as it mimics the module semantics), exports are cached. Therefore, if you create a new module that does all the configuration and then exports `s3`, you can import that anywhere in your application and get the same object back every time.

Comment: Good advice above. Additionally, state should really only contain *data*. It's [not advised to put non-serializable objects](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable) in it